# F# Type provider looks for sample file in referencing project, not referenced project

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have a library where I use `FSharp.Data`'s `JsonProvider` to construct a type from a JSON file. However, when I reference this project in a console application and try to access the generated type, it does not compile, but looks for the sample file in the directory of the console application, yielding an error like

```
Cannot read sample JSON from 'sample.json': Could not find file 'C:\Some\Where\TheSolution\ConsoleApp\sample.json
```

Do I really have to copy the sample file to each referencing project, or do I have to add this as a DLL to get this working, or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You'll have to show your code.

Comment: I'm not allowed as this is company code, but I opened an issue on the respective Github page with steps to reproduce as well: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/1110

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use an F# Data type provider in a library and you reference the library, the compiler will try to access the sample - this is because the types are erased and are recreated each time they are used. (They are also lazily generated, and so they are generated on the fly as they are being used, so this is the only option.)

If you can copy the files with your library, that's probably the best option, but we tried to address this issue - you can embed the sample as a resource and tell the type provider to look for a resource first. See [Using JSON provider in a library](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html) in the F# Data docs:

```
type WB = JsonProvider<"../data/WorldBank.json", 
  EmbeddedResource="MyLib, worldbank.json">
```

This is used, for example, in the [F# Data Toolbox](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.Toolbox/) library. Alas getting this to work well is a bit fiddly.

Comment: Ah, I missed out on that one. However, my concrete example is very simple so I don't need the type provider anyway, but I keep that in mind when I need it for the next time. I also opened an issue on the Github page about that, it is #1110. Should I leave that open as an enhancement suggestion or should I close it?

Comment: If your use case is very simple, you could also use an inline JSON as a sample - that works fine if the JSON is not too long. Regarding the issue - I closed it and copied the answer from here. Thanks for trying to help by reporting it though!